# Drawing listView on Canvas - setAdapter causes NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I've been trying to draw ListView on Canvas, and I get a NullPointerException when I try to set adapter to that listView. I checked it, and it seems listView is null after initialization and I have no idea why.

Here is the code:

```
public class Testing extends Activity {
    MySurface ms;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ms = new MySurface(this);
        setContentView(ms);

        String[] stuffArray = {"stuff1", "stuff2"};
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvListView);   // after this listView is null
        ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stuffArray);

        //listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);     // This line crashes program
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ms.resume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ms.pause();
    }

    public class MySurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
        SurfaceHolder holder;
        Thread t = null;
        volatile boolean isRunning = false;

        public MySurface(Context context) {
            super(context);
            holder = getHolder();
        }

        public void pause(){
            isRunning = false;
            while(true) {
                try {
                    t.join();
                    break;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            }
        }

        public void resume(){
            isRunning = true;
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }

        public void run() {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = li.inflate(R.layout.testing, null);
            v.measure(MeasureSpec.getSize(v.getMeasuredWidth()), MeasureSpec.getSize(v.getMeasuredHeight()));
            v.layout(0, 0, 0, 0);

            while(isRunning){
                if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()) continue;

                Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.translate(50, 50);
                v.draw(canvas);

                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the contents of testing.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="List of stuff:" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat window throws:

```
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testing/com.example.testing.Testing}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226):     at com.example.testing.Testing.onCreate(Testing.java:30)
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
02-17 12:14:56.359: E/AndroidRuntime(9226):     ... 11 more
02-17 12:14:56.369: E/(160): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Comment: is your listViewAdapter null ?

Comment: No, it isn't. Only listView is null.

Comment: could you check if your layout file has this listView in it ? and if it does could you try accessing that to get the listView. Something like : (ListView) ms.findViewById(R.id.lvListView);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got this. It appears android couldn't find R.id.lvListView (which is defined in testing.xml) because testing.xml wasn't set as applications's View, it was merely being drawn on Canvas. This way listView remained null and when I tried to set adapter to it NullPointerException was thrown.

I did it like this:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ms = new MySurface(this);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.addView(ms);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.testing, layout);
        setContentView(layout);
    }
```

It works without a hitch, I can get layout components using findViewById() method.

Thanks anyway for your commitment!